# Get highest value from row - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

I have this query:

```
SELECT tag, filename, timecode, COUNT(tag) AS total 
FROM dados 
WHERE dados.tag = 'movie' 
AND dados.filename = 'movie2.mp4' 
GROUP BY timecode
```

And this is the result:

[image]

But i only want the 3rd row, more precisely the timecode=2 because it's the most consisting tag with the higher value.
How can i grab the highest value of timecode from those rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) with [`LIMIT`](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/)

```
SELECT tag, filename, timecode, COUNT(tag) AS total 
FROM dados 
WHERE dados.tag = 'movie' 
AND dados.filename = 'movie2.mp4' 
GROUP BY timecode
ORDER BY COUNT(tag) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure if limit will work together with group by.  If limit works, I would sugest to add a 'limit 1'

Comment: If you use it with LIMIT it will do what you need

Comment: He wants the row with the highest `COUNT(tag)`, not highest timecode.

Comment: If i use the limit like John said it will print this:
'movie', 'movie2.mp4', '6', '3'

Comment: Change it to `ORDER BY COUNT(tag) DESC`.